# Проблема с реализацией гостевой книжки на php

Tags: php

Всем привет.

Я решил создать эдакого рода прообраз гостевой книжки, функционал которой пока что будет ограничиваться лишь добавлением нового сообщения (пока достаточно лишь разобраться с одним, случай с несколькими разберу позже), а также вывода всех файлов.

Сообщение вводится через html-форму и затем после получения данных выводится вместе с остальными в случае если email введён корректно (если нет - выводится "Error while adding your message").

Всё сообщение состоит из трёх или более строк, первая - для автора, вторая - для почты, остальные - для самого сообщения (причём его нужно обработать так, чтобы весь html-код был через htmlspeacilchars() ). Его нужно поставить в файл типа {текущее время в микросекундах через microtime()}.txt. Все такие лежат в папке messages.

Сам код, если что:

```html
  
<?php
// Guestbook, Гостевая книга
 if (!is_dir("messages")) {
  mkdir("messages");
 };
 $messages = scandir("./messages/");
 if (!$_POST) {
  foreach (glob("./messages/*.txt", GLOB_NOSORT) as $message) {
   $count = 0;
   foreach(file($message) as $line) {
    if ($count !== 1) {
     echo htmlspecialchars($line) . '<br/>';
    } else {
     echo '<a href = "mailto:' . $line . '">' . $line . '</a><br/>';
    };
    $count += 1;
   };
  };
  echo '<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <p><input type="text" name="author" required /></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="email" required /></p>
    <p><textarea name="message" required></textarea></p>
    <p><input type="submit" /></p>
   </form>';
 } else {
  if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false) {
   $author = htmlspecialchars($_POST['author']);
   $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
   $msg = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);
   $time = (int)(microtime(true) * 1000000);
   $content = "$author\n$email\n$msg";
   file_put_contents("./messages/$time.txt", $content);
   array_push($messages, "./messages/$time.txt");
   foreach (glob("./messages/*.txt", GLOB_NOSORT) as $message) {
    $count = 0;
    foreach(file($message) as $line) {
     if ($count !== 1) {
      echo htmlspecialchars($line) . '<br/>';
     } else {
      echo '<a href = "mailto:' . $line . '">' . $line . '</a><br/>';
     };
     $count += 1;
    };
   };
  } else if ($_POST['email']){
   echo 'Error while adding your message.';
  };
 };
?>
```

Подскажите, можно ли каким-либо образом улучшить этот код или, если имеются серьёзные недостатки, указать на них?

Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Почему вы не используете базу данных?

Comment: Как минимум не стоит писать html код в php

Comment: u_mulder, думаю, что папки с файлами на первый раз буде достаточно. Тем не менее, подумаю над Вашим предложением, спасибо.

Comment: Улучшить конечно же можно. Например разбить чтение и запись в разные функции. Цикл с чтением файла также в отдельную функцию запихнуть, он у вас одинаковый по сути. Дальше можно, прикрутить БД. Добавить шаблоны, отделив их от кода и т.д.

Comment: База данных - это стандартный инструмент для хранения данных, предоставляющий огромный функционал для работы с данными - сортировки, фильтрация и прочие плюшки. Вы же со своими файлами сейчас просто занимаетесь бессмысленной работой. И лучше начать делать правильно __сразу__, чем уверять что потом перепишу. Нет, не перепишете. Просто будете делать еще раз с нуля.

Comment: В заголовке написано слово "проблема". Какая именно проблема имеется ввиду?

Comment: советую ознакомиться, с [psr](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/) php. Это правила написания кода,так как я думаю, что код стайл должен прививаться с начала.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С точки зрения обучения, испльзование файлов - **прекрасная** практика. Так что код имеет право на жизнь.

Но его можно улучшить по нескольким направлениям.

1. Убрать бессмыленный код. просто пройдись по коду глазами и убери из него остатки предыдущих попыток (подсказка - переменная $messages)
2. Убрать повторяющийся код. Зачем ты делаешь htmlspecialchars и перед записью, и перед выводом. Зачем ты пишешь код вывода два раза? Почему бы не вынести код вывода из условия, если он все равно должен выполняться в любом случае?
3. Со временем надо обязательно переписать это на использование БД, PDO с sqlite будет прекрасным выбором.
4. Ну и по мелочи

   - `foreach(file($message) as $count => $line) {` даст тебе переменную `$count` без необходимости определять ее специально
   - Зачем здесь `if ($_POST['email']){`? А что будет если емейл пустой?
   - если уж выводишь ошибку, то пиши конкретно: неправильный емейл.
   - использовать GLOB_NOSORT неправильно. Надо убрать этот флаг, и просто отсортировать массив с файлами в обратном порядке. Только такой вариант ганатирует вывод в правильном порядке. Порядок файлов в директори может меняться.